# Email compose view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, actionmailer

I have created and (hopefully set up) a mailer.

Instead of sending templates, I would like to email the content of a form textarea in a view.

I need a view to edit the message, which should be sent to the controller which in turn calls the send_mail method in my mailer.

```
Class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def send_email( email, subject, body )
  mail(
    :to => email,
    :subject => subject
  ) do |format|
    format.text { render :text => body }
  end
end

end
```

This is my view:

```
 <%= form_for(:post, :url => {:action => 'send'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:title, class: 'form-control')%>
    <%= f.text_area(:content, rows: 15)%>
    <%= f.button "Submit", type: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that when generating a mailer with rails g mailer Notifier

I get a notifier.rb in mailers and a notifier folder in views. However I have no view controller for the notifier views.

Question: How do I make the link between my view and sending the input text as email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a controller which handles your view, and in that controller you need to call the mailer somewhat like this: (you'll need to change the names of your form fields to match the params in the call or vice versa)

```
  Notifier::send_email( params[:email], params[:subject], params[:body]).deliver
```

I'd recommend to check out these RailsCasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good place to make **a non-ActiveRecord model**. I understand that right now a problem is solved and this is a bit beyond the scope, but it's useful, so why not?

I suggest you look at [pattern 3 in this article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) and build **a form model** (`Notification`?) that encapsulates the process of storing form contents, validating them and sending the actual email. Note that the implementations in the article are pretty much out of date, Rails 4 introduced `ActiveModel::Model` that facilitates the process.

**Pros:**

- Another class defined mostly in declarative style, easy to read and find
- Can be easily and cleanly laid out by SimpleForm or Rails' form helpers
- Gets all the benefits of a traditional Rails model, like validations (and errors if they fail)
- Semantic, code looks consistent with the rest of the app working with DB or whatever

**Cons:**

- Another class, can be considered overengineering
- More code, some more work, ease of maintenance is arguable
- Another object to create in controllers that render this form

Once it's done, the process of making it work is pretty much the same as making any other resource to work. And I assume, that this mailer sits on its separate page.

Routes:

```
resource :notification, only: [:create] do
  get :new, path: "" # A matter of taste, really
  # You may use the default `new` route
  # with a path `notifications/new`
end
```

Controller:

```
class NotificationsController
  def new
    @notification = Notification.new
  end

  def create
    @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)
    if @notification.send
      # success! redirect somewhere?
    else
      render :new # render the form again with the errors
    end
  end

  private
  def notification_params
    params.require(:notification).permit(:email, :subject, :body)
  end
end
```

You will also need a view for the `new` action that renders the `@notification` into a form. Only `new`, create doesn't need its own. And now for the fun part, model:

```
class Notification # Yep, it inherits nothing!
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_reader :email, :subject, :body

  validates :email,
    presence: true # You might want to validate its format?
  validates :subject,
    presence: true, length: {in: 0..100} # Too long subjects are annoying
  validates :body,
    presence: true

  def persisted?
    false # I have no idea why, but it's defined in the article, no harm done
    # I'd love to hear the explaination about this though
  end

  def send
    if valid? # no objections from validations?
      # Alright, send it already!
      Notifier.send_mail(email, subject, body).deliver
      # thanks for this line go to @Daniel and his answer
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

And, finally, **a pro tip**: Rails 4.2 (bleeding edge right now!) introduced ActiveJob, that's integrated with mailers. By replacing a call to `deliver` method with a call to `deliver_later` you will enqueue the email for sending by the background task processor as described [here (edge guides, subject to change quite soon)](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer). I don't really think it's about time to use it everywhere (too new), but consider this for future projects.

*Do I really think it's good?* Yeah, I really do, I've refactored a user password changer to look this way, the code has become easier to navigate and look at.

Answer (score 0):

So think of your notifier.rb as a controller. In which you defined the #send_mail. This means that in views/notifier you should add a send_mail.html.haml (erb/slim... matter of taste) which will be the body of the mail.

Now from the controller that receives your form you just need to call

```
 Notifier.send_mail(email, subject, body).deliver
```